# C# Database not updating using ASP and EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

My database is not updating with new inserted values from text boxes, but when Account page has loaded, autocomplete with current values from DB works.

What did I miss there ?

It is affected from using Owin on Login/SignIn/LogOut form pages ? 
Because Owin autogenerated few Tabels in my Database and one of them contains userID and password. But i don't think that should be the problem.

Here is my UserInfoModel class:

```
public UserInfo GetUserInformation(string uid)
{
    FarmacieEntities db = new FarmacieEntities();
    UserInfo info = (from x in db.UserInfoes where x.UID == uid select x).FirstOrDefault();

     return info;
}


public void InsertUserInfo(UserInfo info)
{
    FarmacieEntities db = new FarmacieEntities();
    db.UserInfoes.Add(info);
    db.SaveChanges();

}



public string UpdateUserInfo(int id, UserInfo userInfo)
{
    try
    {
        FarmacieEntities db = new FarmacieEntities();

        UserInfo p = db.UserInfoes.Find(id);

        p.Nume = userInfo.Nume;
        p.Prenume = userInfo.Prenume;
        p.Adresa = userInfo.Adresa;
       p.Telefon = userInfo.Telefon;
       p.CodPostal = userInfo.CodPostal;

        db.SaveChanges();
        return p.Nume + " was succesfully updated";

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "Error:" + e;
    }
}
```

And here is my Page code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    string id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    Completare(id);

}

private void Completare(string id)
{

    UserInfoModel model = new UserInfoModel();
    UserInfo user = model.GetUserInformation(id);


    txtNume.Text = user.Nume;
    txtPrenume.Text = user.Prenume;
    txtAdresa.Text = user.Adresa;
    txtTelefon.Text = user.Telefon;
    txtcod.Text = user.CodPostal;

}

private int getID(string id)
{
    UserInfoModel model = new UserInfoModel();
    UserInfo user = model.GetUserInformation(id);

    return user.ID;
}



private UserInfo CreateUser()
{
    UserInfo user = new UserInfo();

    user.Nume = txtNume.Text;
    user.Prenume = txtPrenume.Text;
    user.Adresa = txtAdresa.Text;
    user.Telefon = txtTelefon.Text;
    user.CodPostal = txtcod.Text;

    return user;

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserInfoModel model = new UserInfoModel();
    UserInfo user = CreateUser();


    model.UpdateUserInfo(getID(User.Identity.GetUserId()), user);

    Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Account/Comenzi.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Surely you'd want to `InsertUserInfo` for a new user!

Comment: Are you getting an exception? I note that you catch and squash exceptions using try/catch, and return the error string from your UpdateUserInfo method, but the code which calls that method ignores the returned value, and then redirects anyway (which also destroys it). Have you stepped through the code with a debugger to check it doesn't crash, and also to check that the correct values for id and user are being passed to the UpdateUserInfo method, as you expect?

Comment: Yes i did that and no errors occur

Comment: There won't be an error thrown because you're catching it. Did you set a debug breakpoint within the catch block to check it doesn't enter there? And the `UserInfo p = db.UserInfoes.Find(id);` definitely finds an existing record? And the values in `p` when it's fetched are different to the values in `userInfo` which you're trying to change them to (i.e. we can definitely demonstrate that the tables ought to update? If all those conditions are correct then it ought to work. Are you sure you're pointing at the correct instance of the database?

Comment: All conditions are correct,That's why i posted here, It should work.

Comment: If you're 100% certain about all of those things (which I cannot verify for you) then it looks to me (others may have better eyes) that the code in the question does not (or is insufficient to) reproduce the problem. So either you gave some incorrect code or information, or the problem lies elsewhere in your environment.

Comment: I think that so...

Comment: I suggest that you at least remove all try/catch and see if an error is thrown. When you debugged it, did it step over `db.SaveChanges();` OK? Are you certain you're checking the right database?

Comment: Yes , it passes but no changes...

Comment: So if you run `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE` before and after, you get the same number?

Comment: The problem was on the Page Load function , i forgot to put : if(!IsPostBack) . Now everything works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed:
At the page load function i forgot to add the 2 lines in this if: if(!IsPostBack).

Comment: I don't know how that would make any difference if the `db.SaveChanges();` ran OK .. but I'm glad you solved it